# Is there a way in python to run a different function if a class is called from command line rather than invoked in code?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I have a class as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def my_func_1(self):
        print("This class has been invoked from another code")

    def my_func_2(self):
        print("This class has been called from the command prompt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass()
```

Is there a way to have the class run my_func_1 if it is invoked from a code and my_func_2 if from command line? Also, by from command line I mean by the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The way of calling methods inside classes is by creating an instance of that class and calling the method from that instance.
Even if calling methods could be done from command line it will surely be a bad bad practice.

Comment: I suppose you could add `MyClass.my_func_1 = MyClass.my_func_2` to the `if` clause. That seems like a bad idea though.  What's the context you're using this in?  I think it makes more sense to have multiple implementations of an interface/abstract class, with some factory that determines which is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The context in which I wanted to use this was to have the main class' **init** read the access level of the command line or ask user to login to an admin user. I ended up passing a value which can be true only if the code is ran from command line.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, from_command_line: bool = False):
        if from_command_line:
            my_func_2()
        else:
            my_func_1()

    def my_func_1(self):
        print("This class has been invoked from another code")

    def my_func_2(self):
        print("This class has been called from the command line")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass(from_command_line = True)
```

Like this, if the execution comes from command line, the variable `from_command_line` will be true and in any other case it will be false. Unless someone makes a mistake. Which an exception handling can fix. If you have a better way to do this I would very much like to learn about it.